# Как сделать, чтоб если в файле записан 0 то функция переписывала его на 1 и наоборот?

Tags: php, html

```
    <?php
         $file = "text.txt";
         if (!file_exists($file)) {
            $fp = fopen($file, "w"); // ("r" - считывать "w" - создавать "a" - добавлять 
    к тексту)
            fwrite($fp, 0);
                }
         readfile($file);
         fclose($fp);
     ?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php и https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = 'text.txt';

// Открываем файл для получения существующего содержимого
$current = file_get_contents($file);

if (preg_match("/[01]/", $current)) {
    $i = 0;
    $arr1 = str_split($current);
    foreach ($arr1 as $v) {
        if ($v == '0') {
            $v = 1;
        } elseif ($v == '1') {
            $v = 0;
        }        
        $a[$i] = $v;
        $i++;
    }
    //print_r($a);
    $change_text = implode("", $a);
} else {
    echo "Вхождение цифр 0 и 1 не найдено.";
}

// Пишем содержимое обратно в файл
file_put_contents($file, $change_text);
?>
```